# How to develop a framework both supports iOS and OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks, multiplatform

I want one project that holds all my shared code within the #if and #else definitions, I'd like this code to be able to be built with the 10.10 SDK as well as the iOS 8.1 SDK. Is that possible to make one target(A framework) which both supports iOS and OS X ? or do I have to make 2 separate targets in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Build settings

**Build Settings - > Supported Platform -> iOS OS X**

Comment: I don't think your solution works. Think about it, when I build my project, I have to choose a device, How can a framework builds for an iOS device work on OS X ？

Comment: If you set support platform as OS X and iOS. Then scheme you can see options for both Mac and iOS devices. If you asking creating .a or framework files. You need to uses some script or you need to build for each device then combine all those file as single file.